# What iOS pod uses SCRCException in PrivateFrameworks/ScreenReaderCore.framework ?

Tags: ios, binary, frameworks

We found your app was not in compliance with 2.5.1.

Specifically, it would be appropriate to remove all uses/references to non-public APIs, such as “SCRCException, ScreenReaderCore.framework”, before resubmission.

I recently added Siren & SwiftyStoreKit? any relation?

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be an outdated version of TestFairy :
https://github.com/status-im/status-react/issues/3388

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, yes SCRCException was in TestFairy. I re-submitted without it and the app was accepted. (I upvoted your response, but I don't have status yet for it to be visible.)